# How to create release labels in Git

Tags: git

I use appcelerator and git - building an iOS app.

we have only one developer - and we are place in the dev - where we can do QA and identify issues in the app.

I would like your opinion on how we can tag/label specific build. When we create a iOS build of the app, we want to "label" all the code that went into that build - so we can assign bugs to that version of the code.

one assumption is that we just use describe and tag - and just do like

```
  git tag -a `git describe` 
  git commit -am `git describe`  # or some comment
```

and  the qa person can then

```
git checkout tags/<tag_name>
```

and use the  to reference bugs ?

It's a small team - and we're trying to force a way to use the version number in the app and in the code base - so we can  track bugs/changes.

any ideas will help.

thanks

Comment: to futher clarify, we come using a different system that allows for "labels". so we could easily label like "version_22" and check in. and the build will also contain version 22.  we're trying to replicate that process.

Comment: also - the labeling process would label ALL the files in the work space. so another person can build using that lable to replicate the same version / create the same binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - not an expert - but here is a simple option. if you're using appcelarator, then the app's version is being incremented/changed in tiapp.xml

so first get the version and some comment from tiapp.xml by

```
version=`grep "<version>" tiapp.xml  | sed -e 's/ *<[^>]*>//g'`
```

the create a comment by

```
comments=`grep "<description>" tiapp.xml  | sed -e 's/ *<[^>]*>//g'`
```

then you can

```
git add .
git commit -am $comment
git tag -a $version -m $comment
git push --tags
```

dump all of that in a simple tag-push.sh (or something) and you're set. I am sure there is a more complicated way of doing branches and tags - but this works for me well.

also when you get bigger - you can then have one person do the tagging.